# mvc 5 code first userid as a Foreign Key - How to save data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using MVC5 code first approach.

I haven't changed the user store, added a property called Name in ApplicationUser Class. So it looks like as follows : -

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

I have a company class, which looks like below :-

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A company will definitely has more than one user, but in my design a user can be associated with more than one company. So I have a separate class for CompanyUsers which looks as follows :-

```
public class CompanyUsers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I register a user, I'm setting its role and also companies that the user belongs to, but seems like the UserManager defined in the built-in code has already saved it. So after adding CompanyUsers data, when I call applicationDbContext.Savechanges() it fails as the user has already been saved in the database. Can you tell me how I can achieve it? I can do it in some other logic, like after creating a user, in a separate function assign users to company(s), but I want to know the solution in this circumstances. Also I can redesign the user store.

My modified register function in AccountController is as follows :-

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Name = model.Name };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Role);
                var userCompany = new CompanyUsers
                {

                    Company = _context.Companies.First(t => t.Id == model.CompanyId),
                    User = user
                };

                try
                {
                    _context.CompanyUsers.Add(userCompany);
                    _context.SaveChanges();// throws exception
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                {
                    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("UserViewAll", "Manage");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I have just started mvc code first approach, so I may not understand if you use technical jargon, thanks In Advance for your help!!!!!

Comment: Your Company class needs to contain a `virtual IEnumerable<CompanyUser>`.  Also, I recommend adding the user role to the `CompanyUser` class.  That way a user can have different roles at different companies.

Comment: that's great, can you please explain why company class need virtual IEnumerable<CompanyUser> ?

Comment: Well, the company has users right?  Then they should be on the object.  Put it this way, when you have `company123` you should be able to do `company123.CompanyUsers` to get the list of users for that company.  If lazy loading is available then it will just automatically populate it.  If lazy loading is not available then you'll need to make the call to populate it but either way it will be more natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following code in the `if (result.Succeeded)` block:

```
_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

The issue appears to be that the data context in this method does not know the state of the `user` entity because `UserManager.CreateAsync` uses a separate context. The entity is attached when you assign it to the `CompanyUser` entity, and then this data context tries to save it as a new entity.